# Dynamic text Content

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to implement some sort of "Relations" in my ElasticSearch, based on IDs.

Suppose there is a message in a group...

> "Hello, @someUser is doing a good job..."

Let's call it Document with ID 1

Now, if I just search for the username, I should be able to retrieve the whole message (hello, @someUser...)

> Scenario ->

A document is saved with the content:

`"Hello folks, welcome our new member @David_Foo, blah blah blah"`

And now in our search bar, users if a user searched for @David_Foo or @David, or whatever, our ES will display the above document as a result, *iff* we store the above string as-is.

But suppose @David_Foo replaces his handle/name to @David_Awesome

Now, if a user searched for @David_Awesome, they should still see document 1 in the result.

Is it possible with ElasticSearch?

If so, then how should I proceed? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1):

we can use completion suggester for your problem statement. I have a small POC for your problem. Please check out and let me know if you need any help.

**Mapping**:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "username-suggest": {
        "type": "completion"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now we will insert sample document

```
PUT test/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "title": "Hello folks, welcome our new member @David_Foo, blah blah blah",
  "username-suggest": {
    "input": [
      "David_Foo",
      "David_Awesome"
    ],
    "weight": 34
  }
}
```

and now we will try to searhc either with David_Foo or David_Awesome and we will still get the same result.

**Query**:

```
POST test/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "username-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "da", 
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "username-suggest" 
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "suggest" : {
    "username-suggest" : [
      {
        "text" : "da",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 2,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "David_Awesome",
            "_index" : "test",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "1",
            "_score" : 34.0,
            "_source" : {
              "title" : "Hello folks, welcome our new member @David_Foo, blah blah blah",
              "username-suggest" : {
                "input" : [
                  "David_Foo",
                  "David_Awesome"
                ],
                "weight" : 34
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please checkout this link for more details

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: OMG, that really helped! 
Thanks, man! :) 

Just one question... how will I update my `username-suggest` when @David will change his name?

Comment: Also, what if I search for "Hello folks.... @David_Awesome" i.e. his updated name...
I think for this case, suggester will still work, right?

Comment: You need to update username-suggest array every time when new item got added. I working on C# we have NEST library. Similarly Elasticsearch has clients for all popular languages.

Comment: Hmmm... I see... thanks :) ( I have upvoted your answer, let me test the whole case, and I'll mark it as "answered" later, else this question won't attract much audience! )

Comment: Ok.. Buddy but please do necessary action so that it will reach huge audience.

Answer (score 0):

You can do parent child relationships within the same index in elasticsearch. How ever as per your use case  match phrase prefix query seems suitable please have a look at the link
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer... :) 
But what if the username changes? Do I update my document? Also, `match_phrase` doesn't seem like a good option here :/